# SafariBookmarksSyncAgent going nuts - filling hard drive space with log messages

Tags: icloud, hard-drive, safari, data-synchronization

How to turn off SafariBookmarksSyncAgent forever?

I have noticed my MacBooks pro hdd suddenly showing out of free space notifications (I have a bit more than 30Gb of free space) and after a while this space frees up again.

Activity monitor shows that SafariBookmarksSyncAgent is using around 90% of CPU and Console shows heaps of error messages with text "SandboxViolation: SafariBookmarksS(2819) deny(1) file-read-data ~/Library/Safari-home/lock" and "FileLocker: No lock info supplied; lock is invalid" being logged. Ok, there is something wrong with Safari and I can not figure it out (I tried to give full access right to all Safari files to "everyone") and there is "Lock" directory in Safari which is recreated every time I delete it.

I have unchecked Safari syncing in iCloud preferences - apparently iCloud is trying to sync Safaris bookmarks across all my devices.

I have been trying to deal with this problem for a month but it keeps returning.

Comment: This would seem to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - how certain are you that it is, in fact, the sync agent which is taking up the drive space? Your question shows no link between the two. 30GB free space is critically low anyway.

Comment: I am leaving a chance for other opinions, however there is quite a strong correlation between these three things: sudden (during 10-15minutes) filling of 30Gb space, lots of sync issues being logged and SafariBookmarksSyncAgent using lots of CPU. These three things appear at the same time and disappear at the same time.

Comment: So there is an equal chance the sync issue is a result of the full disk, rather than vice versa

Comment: Well, not really. Sync issues are happening already while hdd is filling up.

Comment: The SyncAgent wrote 2GB in less then 24 hours according to my Activity Monitor.